Best way to insure two cars with my partner
I'm having trouble understanding the best way to organise insurance for two family cars while keeping costs low.
I currently own one car and will shortly take possession of another. Both (for now) will be registered in my name. My partner does not own a car right now, as hers recently went to the scrap yard in the sky.
I have 18 years no claims bonus and she has only 4 years. The quotes we've been given show that me insuring both cars, then adding her as a named driver, will be significantly cheaper than any other option. However, there are some problems with this:

I don't believe this is legal (fronting?) because my partner will be the main driver of at least one of the cars. She'd used it every day to do school runs and drive to work.
My partner would like to accumulate her no-claims discount, which doesn't seem to happen with named drivers, even with multi-car policies.

I've considered letting her take out her own policy on one of the cars, but it looks like insuring a car you do not own means you are only getting liability insurance. It does not cover damage/theft of the car itself. So I'd have to take out my own policy too. It also works out more expensive anyway, even without the extra policy.
I am thinking about handing over ownership of one of the cars to her. She can then take out her own policy, add me as a named driver, and accumulate her discount. But this works out quite a bit more expensive as she can't take advantage of my own bonus. There must be a better way.
Any advice? It all seems messy. Thank you.

The only comment I have is that I have this exact set up (my husband owns 1 car, I own the other and we are both insured as named drivers on the other's car) and our insurer still offers a multi-car discount. Five years is often the max no claims discount anyway, so you wouldn't lose a lot by switching to this set up, and effectively you'd be trading future discount (her NCD) against current premiums.

Your best shot here is probably to have a few different insurance agents quote out exactly what you want including a perhaps a projection of future year premiums assuming clean driving record going forward
Different insurances vary quite a bit so the best strategy might depend on the specific insurance companies and whatever leeway the agents have.

I don't believe this is legal

As long as you fully disclose what you want and all the associated facts, you should be fine. If it's illegal they won't quote it.
Shopping around can really save you money: I had two agents quoting me the same plan from the same insurance company at significantly different prices and both were cheaper then company's own website. You just have to make sure that your "request of quotation" (RFQ) has all details nailed down so you can do a true apples to apples comparison.

Thanks. I found very few that gave quotes online. After doing the maths, I switched my current policy to the new car, putting the cheaper (to insure) car in my partner's name and setting up a separate policy for her. When mine expires, I'll switch to an insurer that supports multi-car, then add her to the group once hers expires next year. It's far too complicated but the timing is not ideal as I'm halfway through my contract!
